# What's the formula for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the generic formula for this calculation?

For example, if *n* = 3 and *x* = 12000, the expanded formula looks like this:

12000 * 1 + 12000 * 2 + 12000 * 3 = 72000

*n* increases by 1 and is multiplied by *x*.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n xk =  x\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k = \frac{xn(n+1)}{2}.$$
Example:
$$f(12000,3)=\frac{12000\cdot3\cdot(3+1)}{2} = 72\,000. $$

Answer (score 1):

Try $x(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})$.

The second term is $\sum_{i=0}^ni$. So we have $x(1 + 2+ \dots + n)$.